# Is there an Apple Touchbar support? [MacBook Pro 16 - 2019]

Tags: drivers, macintosh, software-recommendation

I am wondering if I can use Elementary OS on my new MacBook 16' (2019).

Since I have heard there are numerous problems; supporting the Macs Keyboard and it's Touchbar. Are there any options already out there. If not, I would consider creating this driver in my next year of University.

Greetings,
Niclas

Comment: I think not yet for this MacBook pro, it is new Touchbar without ESC

Comment: Do you know any ressources for older versions?